# Access Web-config appsettings from angular 4, no MVC

Tags: c#, angular

We are developing a website running angular 4 in visual studio (not through node) as a website project. We therefore don't have mvc/razor available. We are also NOT using .NET Core.

We want to be able to access the web.config appsettings in our angular application, where we want to define environment specific variables, such as api endpoint url. The reason we want it specified in the webconfig is because we want to have different transformations of the config for the different environments.

I have set up so that I in my angular application can define constants available through an injection token. I would love to just be able to access my web.config from there, is it possible? If so, how?

This is what my angular app.config looks like:

```
import { InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";

export let APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<IAppConfig>('app.config');

export interface IAppConfig {
    apiEndpoint: string;
}

export const API_CONFIG: IAppConfig = {
    apiEndpoint: 'thisIsWhereIWantMyApiUrl.com'
    //have tried @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiEndpoint"], does not work
};
```

Comment: what have you done sor far?

Comment: @M.Laida Ended up doing it through a json file instead and having octopus switch out the variables depending on environment, were never able to access the web.config

Comment: I've been thinking for a solution for this, unfortunately none works. Maybe you should try to integrate MVC approach to your angular project. I am also trying this approach, I will inform you once I have successfully done it. Here is the link. https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015